# Syntax within a Seam page.xml to output current date?

Tags: jsf, seam

Is it possible to something like the following to assign the 'occurredAt' attribute with a call using Seam's extended support for SEAM EL (seam 2.2)?

```
<navigation>
  <rule if-outcome="search">
   <out name="occurredAt" scope="event" value="#{new java.util.Date()}"/>
   <redirect view-id="/ui/search.xhtml"/>
  </rule>
 </navigation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seam has built-in `#{currentDate}` factory method, so you can write;

```
<navigation>
  <rule if-outcome="search">
      <redirect view-id="/ui/search.xhtml">
         <param name="occurredAt" value="#{currentDate}"/>
      </redirect>
  </rule>
</navigation>
```

and you can access occuredAt parameter from search.xhtml

Comment: I think its called `#{currentDate}`

Comment: To print the current time you can use #{currentTime}.